# Question put on hold as "Too broad." Why was this?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is the question I am speaking of:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952400/looking-for-a-way-to-programmatically-determine-what-markdown-variant-a-website

The question is asking if there is a way to determine programmatically if a website allows (and parses) formatting tags in their input form data.

I had no idea how this stuff worked when asking it. Now, I am presuming the answer is no, or at least I can't think of a way.

I still dont' understand how it is too broad though. If the answer very well is "no, there is no way to do this" that doesn't make the question invalid does it?

I also asked if (assuming the answer is, indeed no) there is any databases that I can make use of that provide this information to me. This seems to be the culprit in making the question "Too broad". However, to me it seems like no one could think of a *single* good answer, so the fact that it got closed because there would be "too many good answers" doesn't seem correct to me.

---

**EDIT:** I guess it is too broad, The only really viable answer would be one that pointed me to a pre-assembled database that I can use, but that is frowned upon here.

I think there should be a place for that on the internet, where people could describe some data they are looking for and people could recommend sources.  (Obviously I'm talking about stuff you can't just easily ask Google)

**EDIT AGAIN:** 
okay, okay I get it, i'm sorry no more down votes, please.

Comment: I'm guessing but you're not asking for a specific solution related to a particular technology. If you had some code that was trying to do what you want, that might be a better starting point and less broad. I kind of disagree with the too broad classification, but I think that's why.

Comment: I meant, you can ask this question on your original SO question itself.

Comment: The second part of your question is blatantly off-topic for SO, asking for open-source databases is asking for a recommendation. We don't do that.

Comment: @bluefeet What if I got rid of that then?

Comment: @LukeP You'd have to get rid of that to even have a chance.

Comment: @bluefeet (just did)

Comment: The question cannot be answered with just a one word answer.  "Yes" or "No" is not a suitable answer.  It would need to explain why it is or isn't possible, and trying to explain why you couldn't do this, or how you could do this, would be too broad.

Comment: @UnderDog What do you mean? as a comment? (I don't want to edit the body of the question, because that actually would make it REALLY off topic and confusing)

Comment: @Servy I just don't see how that is. If the answer is YES, then they give an example of how it is done, this is standard procedure, right? If the answer is No, the explanation might be(I have no way of knowing, its why i asked) : "This si something that gets taken care of completely on the server side, all you can access is the DOM, so no, some sites may give hints, but the process for finding them would be different on a site-by site basis"

Comment: @LukeP: Yes. Ask it there. You will get a quicker answer and much better clarification.

Comment: @LukeP don't worry about the downvotes. You got your clarification. Meta downvotes don't really do anything so, just move on :)

Comment: @LukeP _"no more down votes, please"_ Why do you care as being on MSO? Or did you mean your original question?

Comment: *there should be a place for that on the internet, where people could describe some data they are looking for and people could recommend sources* - there may well be; it just isn't here at SO.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I was talking about the origional, it started with -1, now it has -5 lol. As a side note, this brings up something interesting, because my instinct is to delete the question because clearly the community feels it is low value, but the system in place would punish me (contributes heavily towards a question ban) If I delete a question with a bunch of downvotes

Comment: @KenWhite so true. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 12):

That's...really broad.  I mean, it's ***really*** broad to contemplate.

There's a lot of Markdown variants out there, and most of them would be implemented server-side.  There's also slight tweaks and modifications that could be made to better suit their personal needs, so it might appear that it's a specific *kind* of Markdown, it's really not a dialect that we've seen before.

Since there are a lot of variants, there's also no specification for the threshold of acceptance.  I said before that a variant may *appear* to be one kind, but it could in actuality be modified to suit other purposes, so that wouldn't be an accurate match.

I can't think of any way that this question could be reasonably answered without someone enumerating all possible Markdown variants and then churning through that - regardless of what language you wanted to use.  It's likely a NP-hard solution *at best*; I'm thinking it's NP-complete.

It's too much to be asking for in a question.

Comment: So as you said, because I can not rely on some standard and because I can not expect to find reliable hints on the client-side code, I am asking the impossible?

Comment: I didn't say you *couldn't* do it.  I merely said that it was too broad to be asking in a question here.  If you want to, by all means take a stab at it.  Since I think it's NP-complete, you're going to have a lot of nightmares about the parsing, though.

Comment: can you formulate why it is NP-complete?

Comment: Since, I cant rely on a standard(or standards) How can I possibly determine If my submission of \*text\* is going to result in bold text? take a screenshot and scan the pixels?

Comment: Across all variants of which *N* exist, formulate all legal inputs (of which *M* exist), and determine if the target server (of which *O* exist) will accept or reject that particular input.  Then, determine based on acceptance criteria if this particular server is serving this particular variant.  There's more unknowns to this, namely if it's customized or if there's a lot of things done to make it *feel* like it's one variant, but some other magic is happening in other parts of the parser to make it *not* be that variant.

Comment: Perhaps people think I am asking a different question than I intended to ask and that is why it was closed. You are assuming that "determine if the target server accepts or rejects that input" is something I already know how to do, but actually It is what Im trying to figure out. (I am trying NOT to have to test this for my self on each website)

Comment: Yeah, that's the hard part.  That's what I'm getting at, here.  It's too broad to be asking for several reasons:  You don't define any acceptance criteria, you don't  account for variants and modifications to variants, and there's no good way (in my mind) to fingerprint which version is being employed or not.  Heck, they could even be using Markdown-like parsing but it's not an actual variant of it.  It's just...a ***lot*** to consider for that particular heuristic.

Comment: If it's not a variant of markdown, then what is it? I am assuming most websites use their own, custom markdown, but I was just using the work "markdown" as the opposite of "markup" as in, take some plain text, follow some special rules and turn it into html